# Determine the number of games that can be ordered

Tags: combinatorics

From a deck of 52 cards, cards 2 through 9 of the 4 suits are eliminated. With the rest, determine the number of games that can be ordered:

5 cards with 3 equal to each other and 2 equal to each other.

C4.3 * C4.2 * A5.2

Attemp: You can have A, 10, J, Q, and K. There are 5*4 (which is equivalent to the number of 2 size permutations of a set of 5 elements, which might be the same as A5.2 in op's post)ways to pick the value that appears 3 times and the value that appears 2 times. For the value that will appear 3 times, there are 4C3 ways to pick 3 cards from each suit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a deck of 20 cards with only {A, K, Q, J, 10}.

To find the number of 5 card hands containing 3 of one card and 2 of the other card (e.g., QQQAA) we know that there are $5*\binom{4}{3}$ ways to pick the 3-pair (since there 5 ranks and we are picking 3 out of 4 suits) and $4*\binom{4}{2}$ ways to pick the 2-pair, so the final solution is

$$ (5\times \binom{4}{3}) \times (4 \times \binom{4}{2}) $$

This is just like calculating the probability of a full house in poker. You can look up many resources online about that if you are still confused.